# Displaying a simple tile map properly?

Tags: c#, math

Okay, so I'm trying to display a tilemap, but my math seems to be off.

```
private void MapPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;

            for (int i = 0; i < map.tiles.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < map.tiles[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    int tileXCoord = 0;
                    int tileYCoord = 0;
                    int tileSheetWidth = tileMap.Width / map.tileSize;

                    if (map.tiles[i][j] != 0)
                    {
                        tileXCoord = tileSheetWidth % map.tiles[i][j];
                        tileYCoord = tileSheetWidth / map.tiles[i][j];
                    }

                    Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle((i * map.tileSize) - hScrollValue, (j * map.tileSize) - vScrollValue, map.tileSize, map.tileSize);
                    g.DrawImage(tileMap, destRect, tileXCoord * map.tileSize, tileYCoord * map.tileSize, map.tileSize, map.tileSize, units);
                }
            }
        }
```

Now I'm trying to get my map to use a "word wrapped" tile index

```
[0][1]
[2][3]
```

But it's not working, anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void MapPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;

            for (int i = 0; i < map.tiles.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < map.tiles[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    int tileXCoord = 0;
                    int tileYCoord = 0;
                    int tileSheetWidth = tileMap.Width / map.tileSize;

                    if (map.tiles[i][j] != 0)
                    {
                        tileXCoord = map.tiles[i][j] % tileSheetWidth;
                        tileYCoord = map.tiles[i][j] / tileSheetWidth;
                    }

                    Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle((i * map.tileSize) - hScrollValue, (j * map.tileSize) - vScrollValue, map.tileSize, map.tileSize);
                    g.DrawImage(tileMap, destRect, tileXCoord * map.tileSize, tileYCoord * map.tileSize, map.tileSize, map.tileSize, units);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
tileXCoord = ((currentTile % tilesize) * Imagewidth);
tileYCoord = ((currentTile / tileSize) * Imagewidth);
```

Which work perfectly for me. Do note though that I´m in no way an expert on these sort of things.